# Not able to map fields of different entities with many to many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

DB Schema - 2 tables (user and role) have many to many relationship and are bridged by an intermediate table (user_role) in postgres. I want to fetch all the roles and the name of a person who created it. Name is available in the users table but all the other details are in roles table. Roles table has a field created_by (User_id of the person who created the role).

I am trying to build a GET Request to view all the roles of a given id with the name of the person who created it

**Entity class Users1.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Users1 {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long user_id;

@Column(name = "org_id")
private Long org_id;

@Column(name = "boss")
private Boolean boss;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private Long created_by;


@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_on")
private Date created_on;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "created_by")})

private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

// Getters and Setters
```

**Entity class Role.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2343243243242432341L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Long role_id;

@Column(name = "org_id")
private Long org_id;

@Column(name = "role_name")
private String role_name;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private Long created_by;

@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_on")
private Date created_on;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        mappedBy = "roles")

private List<Users1> users = new ArrayList<>();

// Getters and Setters
```

**roles.repository class**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface RolesRepository extends CrudRepository<Role,Long> {
    @Query(value ="select r.*,u.firstname as firstname 
    from user u 
    join user_role ur  on u.user_id = ur.user_id 
    join role r on ur.role_id = r.role_id 
    where(true = (select u.boss from user u  where u.user_id = ?2) and r.org_id = ?1)
    or 
    (false = (select u.boss from user u  where u.user_id = ?2) and r.created_by =?2)", 
    nativeQuery=true)

    public Iterable<Role> findAllById(Long org_id,Long created_by );


    @Query("from Users1 u where u.user_id=?2 and u.org_id = ?1")
    public Users1 findUserbyOrgId(Long org_id, Long created_by);

}
```

**roles.Controller class :**

```
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Role>> getAllRoles(@RequestParam("org_id") Long org_id, 
@RequestParam("created_by") Long created_by ) throws Exception {

        if( null != rolesRepository.findUserbyOrg(org_id, created_by)) {
            Iterable<Role> Roles = rolesRepository.findAllById(org_id, created_by); }

GET Response from postman:
[
    {
        "roleId": 3,
        "org_id": 2,
        "roleName": "manager",
        "createdBy": 5,
        "createdOn": 1591716178419,
    }
]
```

**I'm getting everything except the firstname. I'm not sure how to fetch that in my GET API. Any help would be really appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

**Not a direct answer to your question**, but @ManyToMany is generally not encouraged in the real field due to the following reasons.

- The joining table may need to have more information (but can't)
- Since the joining table is hidden, query result is hard to anticipate.

The recommended approach is to

- decompose two @ManyToMany classes to two @OneToMany classes + 
  one @ManyToOne class (joining table)
- elevate the joining table to an entity class.

There are many practices of such cases in stackoverflow and youtube. I think it will ultimately save you more time to switch to this approach.